# How to add evm and ethereum pallet from scratch into substrate node?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node, evm, ethereum

I want to add evm pallet and ethereum pallet into my substrate node from scratch, so how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are totally new first take a look into the Substrate Documentation: [Add a pallet to the runtime](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/).

Then take a look into the [Frontier Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/), it is a template node that has this two pallets:

> A FRAME-based Substrate node with the Ethereum RPC support, ready for hacking

Specifically how is adding the [EVM pallet](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L308) and the [Ethereum pallet](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L326) in the runtime, and how is using the [chain_spec](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L165) to have some initial configuration.

Finally check the Susbtrate Documentation: [Access EVM accounts](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/) to learn how to interact with your pallets.

Answer (score 0):

You may take reference from  some of the chains which have already integrated `pallet_evm` & `paller_ethereum` into substrate some e.g are [ChainX](https://github.com/chainx-org/ChainX) & [Reef-chain](https://github.com/reef-defi/reef-chain) & [Selendra](https://github.com/selendra/selendra)